# jquery appear on scroll and each element after each other

Tags: jquery, animation, html, scroll, fadein

I was wondering how they fixed this kind of effect:

On scroll to `<div class="div1"></div>`

It shows image 1 with fade in, Than image 2 with fade in, than image 3 with fade in, etc etc..

http://www.neotokio.it/ did this, but i cant seem to figure it out..

What i have so far is:

```
tiles = $(".test1").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(900,1);
    });
})
```

so it appears on scroll, to a certain div, but i have no clue how to fix it to make more animations in 1 div, as i mentioned above. and as example neotokio.it.

Comment: to me more specific, i ment the DIV "SERVICES" with the words and round shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does pretty much what your looking for, where I have taken 650 off the div position you would probably want to get the use `$(window).innerHeight()` to get the height of the viewport and make a calculation from that.

Style:

```
body{
    height: 1000px; 
}

div#container{
    margin-top: 800px; 
    display:block; 
    height:50px; 
    width:300px;
 }

.tiles{
    display:inline-block; 
    height:40px; 
    width:90px; 
    opacity:0; 
    background-color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
         <div class="tiles">tile1 content</div>
         <div class="tiles">tile2 content</div>
         <div class="tiles">tile3 content</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var divpos= $("#container").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= divpos-650) {          
          var animDelay = 0;
              $('.tiles').each(function(){
                  $(this).delay(animDelay).animate({
                      opacity:1
                   },500);
                   animDelay += 500;
              });
         clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 250);
```

Hope this helps - see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/24M3n/28/

Comment: could you fiddle this with the code i made, cuz i dont quite understand, sorry. im a noob in jquery.

Comment: do you have a link so I can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to make this work on this site: and than for some elements in this site, lets say the image of tagcloud. http://envato.dlvdesign.nl/dlvdesign2/

Comment: have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/24M3n/28/ I have included some tiles with an offset animation, hopefully this will show you how to go about this, as I said in a live site you will want to calculate the correct window height

Comment: WAUW Awesome, thank you very very very very very much! do you have a idea how to calculate the hight of the window? (last question) sorry for stalking haha.

Comment: I want to thank you for your kindness to help me WebweaverD, you helped me allot! thanks again!